# XSS in socket.io/node.js chat?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, xss

Okay, so I've been trying to fix the xss on my website, all times failed.
There is string called 'name' in whitch people change their name to something like 
    `<script>alert("HahS");</script>` I already tried

```
name = name.replace(/(<|>)/g, '');

if(name.indexOf('<') !== -1){
return false;
}
```

All I managed to do, is fix xss on the the user who sent the xss, but for all other people logged it still pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own regex for this. Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), which is the proper way to escape user input like this.

```
const sanitized = encodeURIComponent(name);
```

The trick is that you need to do this in the right place. If your `name` parameter is being broadcast to other clients, you need to decide where you want to escape it. Generally, it is best to do this right before the data is *rendered* or used in such a way that would be dangerous if not escaped.

This implies:

1. Doing it on the client, rather than on your server.
2. Doing it when the client initializes / renders, rather than when the potentially malicious user submits their name.

If you are having a hard time figuring out where the right place is, just add `encodeURIComponent()` everywhere you use `name` and work backwards (figure out where you can remove it). You will probably end up with `name` being double-escaped in the mean time. But that's okay for most innocent values of `name` and it is a better default than being open to XSS attacks.

More details:

- http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I'm having a hard time adding encodeURIComponent() everywhere I use name, example there is a "bet.name" and if i change it to "bet.encodeURIComponent(name)", the site doesn't even work at all.

Comment: If the value is stored at `bet.name`, then you need to use `encodeURIComponent(bet.name)`. Does that work?

Comment: I guess it works but its very  bad, even the spaces "%20" shows up. Is there any way to make it better looking (only remove <,> etc)?

Comment: Yes, you could try writing an alternative to `encodURIComponent()` that only encodes the bare minimum of reserved characters for where you are rendering the data. But the thing is, each character you let slip through could be another weapon that gets used against you. So it would be wise to read the specs. The easy way is to disallow certain characters at input time (like no spaces in a username).